# How to dispatch a lambda expression to a background (non-UI) thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am looking to perform this action:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            ... // do some UI specific stuff
        });
```

But instead of sending the lambda expression to the UI thread, I want to send it to a background worker.

The situation is as such, I have a messagebox whose response I need to have to know whether or not to do some additional processing (in this case copy a file).

How can one accomplish this? I am open to a refactor solution of sorts that does not include a lambda expression dispatch.

Thanks for reading

Comment: So you mean you need to invoke something in background thread? or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope.  Doesn't make sense.  MessageBox runs on the UI thread, so when it returns from its modal display, you're on the UI thread.  You'd run your lambda on a background thread (e.g., ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem), then when that finishes use the dispatcher to return to the UI thread.  But you need the dispatcher from the UI thread; not sure if it is different than the one you mention in your code.

Comment: @Will Yes, so I'll look into ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. Thanks

Comment: @Will QueueUserWorkItem definitely worked. If you want to make that an answer I'll mark it as the right one. Thanks again

Comment: Your comment says "UI specific stuff".  If it's UI stuff, it needs to be in the UI thread.  If it's *not* UI stuff, then it can be in a non-UI thread.

Comment: @Servy Yeah I chose a bad example then. I was just showing what is done for dispatching to the UI thread, and then the line underneath asks for the opposite thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MessageBox runs on the UI thread, so when it returns from its modal display, you're on the UI thread. Dispatching to the UI dispatcher at this point doesn't make sense.

You'd want to run your lambda on a background thread (e.g., ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, via a Task, etc), then when that finishes use the dispatcher to return to the UI thread. But you need the dispatcher from the UI thread; not sure if it is different than the one you mention in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you'd be looking at something like this. First show a messagebox on the UI thread, wait for the result and if required dispatch some work to a background thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            //Show messagebox
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Question?", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            //Check messagebox result
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
                {
                    //Do some work, transfer a file
                });
            }
        });
```